# Dimension of image of Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there a method to calculate the dimension of the set of vectors in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ $\{\ [A,B] \ \text{s.t} \ B \in \mathfrak{su}(n)\}$ for some fixed $A$. Is the dimension the same for all $A$?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the linear operator ${\rm ad}(x)$, defined by ${\rm ad}(x)(y)=[x,y]$ has
a non-trivial kernel $ker (ad(x))$, since we always have $[x,x]=0$, and an image ${\rm im}(ad(x))$. As you know, we have
$$
\dim \ker(ad(x))+\dim im(ad(x))=\dim (L)
$$
for all $x\in L$.
The dimensions $\dim im(ad(x))$ are not always the same, e.g., take $x=0$, and take an $x\neq 0$ with non-trivial adjoint operator.

Comment: Is there an example in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ of two non-zero values for $A$ which yield different dimensions?

Comment: Yes. Take $ad(x)$ being a diagonal matrix of trace zero. The dimensions can be different, according to the number of zeros on the diagonal - if $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Can it be different if $A$ is not allowed to have any repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: The best answer is, that you want to try this yourself for $n=3$. Write $x=\lambda_1e_1+\cdots +\lambda_8e_8$ as a linear combination of the basis. Now determine all possible dimensions of $ad(x)$ according to any choice of the $\lambda_i$.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks. Do you have a reference for this? Or a keyword?